# json decode japanese string not working

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode json string containing Japanese words.I have tried

```
 $rec_data= '{"id":"220011","name":"を送"}';
 $data = json_decode(utf8_encode($rec_data),TRUE);
 var_dump($data);
```

but it returning

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(6) "220011" ["name"]=> string(8) "ð" }
```

I want it to be

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(6) "220011" ["name"]=> string(8) "を送" }
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: isn't very likely that `$rec_data` is a iso-8859-1 encoded string

Comment: why you use `utf8_encode($rec_data)`???

Comment: This is working for me:<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
$rec_data= '{"id":"220011","name":"を送"}';
$data = json_decode($rec_data,TRUE);
var_dump($data);
?>

Comment: without utf8_decode , json_decode returns NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` when you encode your array to `json`.

[Online link](https://3v4l.org/Ju2q7) for testing.

```
$array =  array("id"=> "220011", "name" => "を送");
$rec_data = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$data = json_decode($rec_data, TRUE);

var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(6) "220011" ["name"]=> string(6) "を送" }
```

Comment: I am getting array(2) { ["id"]=> string(6) "220011" ["name"]=> NULL }

Comment: Did yo check the online link??

Comment: @Shashikala Probably your data is not **utf-8**. Japan, usually they are using ShiftJIS, SJIS,...